# How to pass path generated via askdirectory() method from one callback to other in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need path of folder selected by user in `vid_downloader()` function. But both functions are bound to different buttons. How can I solve this problem?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import SUNKEN
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.font import BOLD

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Youtube Downloader")
root.config(bg="purple")
root.geometry("500x300")

def selectdir():
    path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="C:/Users/DRB/Desktop", title="Select download folder")

def vid_downloader():
    url = url_field.get()
    path= "???"


url_field = tk.Entry(root, relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=2)
url_field.pack(expand=True, fill="x", padx=10, pady=10)

locatioin_button = tk.Button(root, text='Select folder', command=selectdir,bg="green",fg="white", font=(BOLD))
locatioin_button.pack(expand=True, fill="x", padx=10)

download = tk.Button(root, text="Download", command=vid_downloader, bg="black",fg="white", font=(BOLD))
download.pack(expand=True, fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you considered defining `path` as a global variable?

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for better solution if there is.

Comment: How do you define "better"? The better solution arguably would be to use classes, is that the sort of answer you're looking for? Though, in such a small program there's absolutely nothing wrong with using global variables.